# google search for term contained in the URL but before the slash

Tags: url, google-search

A while ago I learnt of and started using

```
site:example.com  something
```

..to search for something on just that one domain.

```
site:.ie  something
```

..was handy to search for something on for example the Irish top level domain

Then today I learned

```
inurl:terminurl    something
```

..which forces the something to be found upon a url containing a certain term in the url.

It did not do what I was hoping though, I wanted it to only search within URLs for which the given term appeared *before* the first slash. In other words the search upon the domain needs to be restricted to the

- subdomain
- second-level domain
- top-level domain

..but not return a hit if the term appears for example in the *subdirectory* part of the URL. `inurl:` looks anywhere in a potentially very long URL for a term.

Does anyone know if this is possible and how to do it?

I wrote 'Google' but actually mean any search engine on which these things work, I notice that they seem to work on duckduckgo as well.

Comment: https://technastic.com/google-search-operators-list/ - fantastic reference for this

Comment: Had another complex search thing come up today `-site:.ie   something` finds _something_ everywhere _but_ on the Irish TLD